# Set hostname with Python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, hostname, computer-name

I have searched some libraries for python (os, platform, socket), but I can't seem to find how to set/write/configure the hostname (computer name). I know how to get it, but I need to know how to set it. This for Windows 10 computers.

If anyone has any tip, thanks!

Comment: you would have to do it using windows "native" tool , like wmic or powershell . 
and administrator privilege is also required.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, I'm gonna use powershell instead, thanks